# Запрос на выдачу всех постов\поста

Tags: mysql, база-данных, node.js

Есть сервер API на node.js express mysql.

База данных состоит из 4 таблиц:

```
твиты, комменты к твиту, хэштеги, твит_хэштег (many-to-many)
```

Представим что клиент зашел на главную страницу, с клиента летит запрос для получения всех твитов.

**Вопрос:**

Отправлять ли ему только твиты, и позволить ему самому запрашивать коменты поста и на его теги другими запросами, или сделать на сервере 3 запроса сгенерируя ему объект ответа, аля

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    text:"Hello",
    comments:[],
    tags:[]
  }
...
]
```

В которых уже будут включатся комменты и теги твита?

Проблема в том что не могу одним запросов вытащить желаемый объект как выше, ибо это как таблица результатов запроса, в таблице результата запроса, comments и tags это отдельные запросы, и я не знаю как в mysql сделать так чтобы

```
SELECT 
  p.*,
  comments(
     SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE post_id=p.id
  ) 
FROM posts
```

Comment: а почему не можешь? просто не знаешь как? Можно соединять таблицы с помощью `LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN` по нужным ключам

Comment: не знаю как, ну сейчас оно выглядит так
SELECT p.*, c.id as c_id, c.text as c_text,c.owner_id as c_owner, c.created_date as c_date from posts p
            LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id=p.id

Comment: суть в том что мне нужно соеденить таблицу результатов с одним полем в posts

Comment: то есть поле comments должно указывать на таблицу результатов запроса для комментов

Comment: а если так SELECT ..., (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE {какое то условие, например postId=4}) as comments FROM posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Реляционные базы так не используют.** Это уже реверанс в сторону NoSQL.

Каждый запрос должен возвращать ровно один набор строк, в котором размещены **одинаковые сущности**. Исключения бывают, но они редки и обычно касаются функциональности, **специфичной для конкретных баз данных**, и клиент БД ещё и не всегда такое поддерживает.

В PostgreSQL колонка может иметь тип "массив значений", но в MySQL, насколько мне известно, такого типа нет. А значит, всё равно придётся для получения комментариев делать отдельный запрос и составлять ответ (JSON) на уровне приложения.

И пока таких запросов константное число, не зависящее от результатов промежуточных запросов (`O(1)`), бояться тут нечего.

Comment: Вот то что я хотел сказать, когда работал с Mongo такой проблемы не было, а тут ввело в замешательство :),
Но вопрос же остается, стоит ли сразу делать 3 запроса, или позволить клиенту сделать 3 запроса, для постов, комментов, тегов,

Клиент пишу на React.js

Comment: @ОлегАндреев тогда конечно разбивай, react с redux позволяют легко организовать такой функционал. Проще все сделать асинхронно, и когда пользователю будет нужно, он сам запросит нужное

Comment: @ОлегАндреев Mongo не реляционная база и она для других целей :) Стоит ли делать отдельные запросы это уже зависит от юзкейсов в вашем API: всё-таки комментарии не являются *непосредственной частью* поста, и с одной стороны, можно уменьшить кол-во совершаемых HTTP-запросов, но с другой каждый такой запрос будет потенциально тянуть лишние данные. Решение за вами, советовать тут нельзя.

Comment: Благодарю, так как клиент пишу сам, то привык посылать несколько запросов для таких случаев, но не знал правильно ли я делаю (студент пока увы), в таком случае создам буду посылать 3 запроса, спасибо большое)

Comment: @ОлегАндреев тут "правильного варианта" не существует, надо прикинуть последствия в каждом случае и выбрать меньшее зло :)